# Multiple dynamic query in Linq

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, dynamicquery, predicatebuilder

First of all, I will explain the table structure

```
First table Attribute          Second table Category

Id       Name            Id     Name    AttributeId(Foreign Key)
------------------      -----------------------------------------
1      Material          1      Cotton   1
2      Size              2      Black    3
3      Color             3      White    3
                         4      Linen    1

Third Table ProductCatLink

Id     CategoryId(Fk Category table)   ProductId(FK of Product Table)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1         1                                     5
2         2                                     6
3         2                                     5
4         4                                     6
5         4                                     7
6         3                                     8
```

Consider user selects material cotton and color black and white then result must be

```
 Id       CategoryId     ProductId(ForeignKey of Product Table)
 ---------------------------------------------------------------
    1         1               5
    2         2               5
```

Consider user selects material cotton and linen and color black and white then result must be

```
Id       CategoryId     ProductId(ForeignKey of Product Table)
-------------------------------------------------------------------
    1         1               5
    2         4               6
    3         2               5
    4         1               6
```

user passes categoryid array from UI like `{1,2,3}(cotton material with black or white color)` or `{1,4,3} (cotton or linen material with black color)` must group with attribute id to achieve this.

I tried different way using contains but not working properly, if checking each product with all category using custom loops works fine but comparing each products with all condition causes performance issue.

Is there any simple solution for this problem?
Is there any solution using Predicatebuilder in linq?

any code snippets on how to achieve this using linq will be helpful

I done it like this is there any performance issue with it?

```
 ExpressionStarter<Products> ProductPredicater(params int[] categories)
          {
                var predicate = PredicateBuilder.New<Products>();
                var catwithAttributes = from cat in categories.AsEnumerable()
                                        join pSubCat in 

                 _productSubCat.GetAll().AsEnumerable()
                                    on cat equals pSubCat.Id                                    
                                    select pSubCat;

              var attributeids = catwithAttributes.GroupBy(m => 
              m.AttributeId).Select(m => m.Key);
          

            foreach (int keyword in attributeids)
            {
                var subcatlist = catwithAttributes.Where(m => m.AttributeId == keyword).Select(m => m.Id).ToList();
                predicate = predicate.And(p =>  p.ProductCategoryLinkDetails.Any( l=> subcatlist.Contains(Convert.ToInt32(l.ProductSubCategory_Id))));                
            }

            return predicate;
        }


var result =   from p in products.Get(ProductPredicater(input.ProductCategoryId), 
               null, m => m.ProductCategoryLinkDetails) select p;
```

Comment: Pull you table data in `cache` memory then you have better performance. These are called [EAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) tables that have performance issues when have heavy query.

Comment: If there are any query based solution, I will really appreciate that

Comment: *"I tried different way using contains but not working properly"* And what were those attempts, you've not show any of them in your question.Why didn't those attempt work? What is your specific question here? *"Is there a simple solution"* is just a yes or no question; what is the programming question you have here?

Comment: @Larnu I am not talking about the full code solution, if I get any snippets and some logic I can work out, thanks..

Comment: @Larnu I tried, check my edit

Answer (score 1):

Very hard to understand your question, but I think I get idea. Looks not performant but I'll update answer when find better solution.

```
var materials = new[] { 1 };
var colors    = new[] { 2, 3 };

var query = from p in db.Products
   where 
     p.ProductCatLinks.Any(l => materials.Contains(l.CategoryId)) &&
     p.ProductCatLinks.Any(l => colors.Contains(l.CategoryId))
   select p;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but the problem here is material can be multiple and colors can also be multiple, can refer Amazon or some other eCommerce website same is happening here.

Comment: Updated answer, which is obvious.